# How to convert a picture in pure black and white in Rust

Tags: image-processing, rust

I want to convert a picture in pure black and white(e.g. no grayscale) using `Image` crate, the result should be a picture with 0 and 255 RGB values.

Following the [docs](https://crates.io/crates/image) i've wrote the following:

```rust
let img = image::open("photo.jpg").unwrap(); // Load picture
let gray_img = img.grayscale(); // Convert it

// Access a random pixel value
let px = gray_img.get_pixel(0,0);
println!("{:?}", pixel.data); // Print RGB array
```

The problem here is that, whatever pixel i print, it gives me grayscale value.
So, is there a function to convert an image in pure black and white? Something like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/index.html)'s convert function for Python?

Comment: Don't you want to `dither` to a BiLevel map ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for...however official doc does not say so much about dithering...can you elaborate an answer?

Comment: yes I guess I can show you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you can first build a grayscale image then dither it to a Black and White one:

```
use image::{self, imageops::*};

let img = image::open("cat.jpeg").unwrap();
let mut img = img.grayscale();
let mut img = img.as_mut_luma8().unwrap();
dither(&mut img, &BiLevel);
img.save("cat.png").unwrap(); // this step is optional but convenient for testing
```

You should of course properly handle errors instead of just doing `unwrap`.

Comment: Somebody should probably improve the crate's doc with more examples like this one. It's not obvious without reading the source.

Comment: Thanks for your help...however i don't fully understand how `BiLevel`(so a `ColorMap`) should be implemented.

Comment: What do you mean implemented ? You don't have to implement it. Do you mean you want another dithering algorithm ? Here's [the implementation of BiLevel](https://docs.rs/image/0.21.2/src/image/imageops/colorops.rs.html#192)

Comment: Never mind, i haven't imported BiLevel from `image::imageops::colorps` module, so the compiler gave me an error...now everything works!

Comment: @bzoark Sorry for that, I'll add the use statements to my answer (don't directly import from colorops: it's reexported in imageops)